# Why does this method for differentiating work?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, recreational-mathematics

Consider the function 
$$f(x)=x^x.$$
If I differentiate with respect to $x$ treating the exponent as a constant and then sum the derivative treating the base as a constant, I get
\begin{align}
f'(x)&= xx^{x-1}+x^x\ln x\\
f'(x)&= x^x(1+\ln x).
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Good observation and indeed there is a deeper meaning.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and $i:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be given by $i(x)=(x,x)$. Then

$$(f\circ i)'(x)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x)$$

This can be seen as a special case of [the multi-dimensional chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions) (the "$+$" part comes from the matrix multiplication).

In your case $f(x,y)=x^y$ (obviously not defined everywhere but the chain rule still holds on open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Comment: This is what I considered writing until I saw yours. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Take logarithms and implicitly differentiate
$$
\ln y = x \ln x\\
\frac{y'}{y} = \ln x + 1
$$
To compute the derivative of the right-hand side, you are essentially doing the same manipulation you are describing without taking the logarithms -- which is why it works in this case...

Answer (score 0):

You can prove it by the logarithmic differentiation.

$$ y= x^x$ \implies \ln y = x\ln x$$

$$ \frac {y'}{y} = \ln x +1 $$

$$ y'= y(\ln x +1) = x^x(\ln x +1)$$

See if you can generalize it $y= f(x) ^{g(x)}$